# Use Maven-build-cache for submodules under parent pom

Tags: maven, caching, build

I have a maven project with 2 modules and a parent pom as such

```
<modules>
    <module>api</module>
    <module>service</module>
</modules>
```

I would like to take advantage of the maven cache extension and I've added it in the build section of the parent pom as such

```
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-build-cache-extension</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
```

I've also added a maven-build-cache-config.xml                                                           file however it would seem that every time I run `mvn clean package` a different checksum is generated for my submodules and as a result I don't actually benefit from the caching since all my java files are in those submodules

I've tried multiple configs with no luck unfortunately

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<cache xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/BUILD-CACHE-CONFIG/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/BUILD-CACHE-CONFIG/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/cache-config-1.0.0.xsd">
    <configuration>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <hashAlgorithm>XX</hashAlgorithm>
    </configuration>
    <input>
        <global>
            <glob>{*.java,*.xml,*.properties}</glob>
            <includes>
                <include>recursive=api/*</include>
                <include>recursive=service/*</include>
            </includes>
        </global>
    </input>
</cache>
```

How can I make this extension actually cache the contents of my submodules with the same checksum if there haven't been changes. I know this extension is fairly recent and I haven't been able to find any hits online.

**EDIT**

Commenting one of the child modules out, actually ended up working and the cache is kicking in correctly. Is it possible there's a limitation to the extension in that it scans for a single module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the issue was a "false alarm". In my api module I have a swagger file which would generate POJOs in the `ignore-generated` folder, so the fix is to add the following within this particular module and then everything is working as expected with proper caching in place.

```
<properties>
        <maven.build.cache.exclude.ignore-generated>${project.basedir}/ignore-generated</maven.build.cache.exclude.ignore-generated>
</properties>
```

Comment: is the "ignore-generated" on the "maven.build.cache.exclude.ignore-generated" comes from the fact that the ignored directory is named as "/ignore-generated"?
I need to ignore the jaxb generaged sources in directory called "generated-sources/xjc", do I use "<maven.build.cache.exclude.ignore-generated>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/xjc</maven.build.cache.exclude.ignore-generated>
</properties>"?

Comment: I believe yes this is defined in the maven build cache extension itself, so this should probably work for you

Answer (score 0):

That's really weird.  The input configuration is used on a per-module basis.  You need to raise a JIRA issue and attach a small project to reproduce the problem so that it can be further analysed.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me, I did find the JIRA project https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/MBUILDCACHE/issues/MBUILDCACHE-35?filter=allopenissues but I have no account there. Is it possible to create the issue and see if someone would know a solution based on the syntax? I can try and build out a sample project and see if it can be reproduced

Comment: You can create an account using https://selfserve.apache.org/jira-account.html afaik.